# Do props from state overwrite props from parent, using React-Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

When using React+Redux do parent props overwrite props from state, or do props from state overwrite props from parent components (this is, if the names of the props clash)?

```
interface OwnProps {
  //The type for the props provided by the parent component
}

function mapDispatch(dispatch: AppDispatch<any>) {
  return { dispatch };
}

function mapState(state: RootState) {
  return {
    s: {
      // props from state are namespaced onto s
    }
  };
}

type StateProps = ReturnType<typeof mapState>;
type DispatchProps = ReturnType<typeof mapDispatch>;
type AllProps = StateProps & DispatchProps & OwnProps;

const ResetPassword: React.FC<AllProps> = (p) => {
  ///
}
```

Comment: do people not understand the question? if it has an existing answer, then I would understand the downvotes, but if not...

Comment: Have you tried testing it?

Comment: I would expect the props you return from `mapStateToProps` to take precedence. Since `mapStateToProps` has a second argument (`ownProps`), which allows you to decide what to do with state props and props passed to the component from a parent component. But it's easy to test I guess.

Comment: @timotgl - umm how does that work if you don't use the second argument (ownProps)? does it just Object.assign everything? it doesn't actually make sense

Comment: @OlegzandrDenman See my answer below. If you don't use ownProps, normal React behavior is still there and the props from mapStateToProps and the parent component get merged together. But mapStateToProps can overwrite props with the same name if you return any.

Answer (score 2):

You can control this behaviour by using the second parameter in `mapStateToProps`, which provides you with the component's own props. Here is an example:

```
function MyComponent({ myProp }) {
    return (
      <div>{myProp}</div>
    );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
    // use myProp from props first, and fall back to some value from state.
    myProp: ownProps.myProp || state.whatever.property, 
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponent);
```

Otherwise, all props with equal names would be overriden by properties of the object that `mapStateToProps` returns.

Answer (score 0):

```
const Component = ({ testProp }) => (
  <div>testProp: {testProp}</div>
);

const mStP = () => ({
  testProp: 'testProp from mapStateToProps',
});

const ConnectedComponent = connect(mStP)(Component);
```

Then do this somewhere in your App component:

```
<ConnectedComponent testProp="testProp from parent component" />
```

As you can see, `mapStateToProps` decides the value of `testProp`. If you wanted to preserve the value passed by the parent component, simply don't put `testProp` in the object returned by `mapStateToProps`.

If you don't use the second `ownProps` argument in `mapStateToProps`, all the props passed to `ConnectedComponent` still end up there - Redux doesn't interfere with the default React behavior.

Comment: so mapStateToProps will overwrite props with the same name from parent..